# How do I join two tables and create an additional column with comma seperated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, join

I don't have much experience with SQL apart from CRUD queries; please forgive me if this is trivial. I am trying to join two tables and create an additional column in the results with a series of comma seperated values.

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

I can get the comma seperated values from table 2 using

```
DECLARE @tmp varchar(MAX)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp = @tmp + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [materialTypeID])  + ', '
FROM [industryActivityMaterials] 
WHERE typeID = 1145 AND activityID =  1
SELECT SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp)) AS materialsRequired
```

[image]

I can't figure out though how to join the tables together on the `typeID` to contain a set of results containing the column of `materialsReguired`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join, aggregate, and use aggregate function `string_agg()` to generate the comma separated list. This function is available since SQL Server 2017.

```
select 
    t1.typeID, 
    t1.activityID,
    t1.activityName,
    t.Blueprint,
    t1.productTypeID,
    t1.ProductName,
    string_agg(t2.materialTypeID, ',') 
        within group (order by t2.materialTypeID) materialTypeIDs
from 
    table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on  t2.typeID = t1.typeID
        and t2.activityID = t1.activityID
group by
    t1.typeID, 
    t1.activityID,
    t1.activityName,
    t.Blueprint,
    t1.productTypeID,
    t1.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

below 2016 sql server version you can use xml path to group by string concat

```sql
SELECT 
  T1.typeId,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + materialTypeID 
    FROM Table2 T2 
    WHERE (T2.typeId = T1.typeId) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS materialsRequired
FROM Table1 T1
GROUP BY T1.typeId
```

over sql server 2016 version you can use `string_agg`.

[STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

As a note, regardless of approach, you might find a correlated subquery simpler than a big aggregation:

```
select t1.*,
       (select string_agg(t2.materialTypeID, ',') within group (order by t2.materialTypeID)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.typeID = t1.typeID and
              t2.activityID = t1.activityID
       ) as materialTypeIds
from table1 t1;
```

Or:

```
select t1.*,
       stuff( (select concat(',', t2.materialTypeID) 
               from table2 t2
               where t2.typeID = t1.typeID and
                     t2.activityID = t1.activityID
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as materialTypeIds
from table1 t1;
```

In general, avoiding the outer aggregation improves performance, especially if there is an index on `table2(typeID, activityId)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will try your apporach also.